# Android: pass property to signed apk

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I need to pass a property to a signed apk file.
Property represents a simple int value.

Restrictions:
1. apk file is very large - over 150Mb

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "pass a property"?

Comment: @PozzoApps write it somewhere in apk or somewhere in a specific device, so I can read it from my application after installation. But my apk file is already signed and very large, so any operations with changing it`s resources - is not good way.

Answer (score -1):

To manipulate apk file directly is tricky, so I do not recommend, what you should do is prepare your app before generating the apk file to read from a file on SD Card or from a WebService this 'settings'.

150 MB is a really huge file, you probably should take a look in options to divide this file from this resources, it should make it easier to compile each time.

Comment: I see, this value represents unique id of application which is needed to be set to apk just before download or to be passed to device before download, so application can read it after installation. For downloading apk files I`m using my own web server. My apk was about 280Mb few days ago:) It`s a game.

Comment: What about reading files from SDCard, is there a way of writing files to SDCard in anroid via javascript?

Comment: Ow, I see your problem now... You are trying to not let users copy a 'cracked' version of your app... well, I know there is a lot of bets developed solutions, but maybe you could save some unique device id? I know there is some of them, inclusing IMEI, but I suggest to test it before apply, especially with Chinese devices.

Comment: -1 untrue; apk files are just zip files and trivially modified.  The signing information is not stored for the apk as a whole but rather for each contained file.

Comment: sadly, I can't down vote your comment, but I think the misunderstood one here is you... explain your self pleas.